# IE padding-right issue with bg image in input

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, input

I am facing an issue with IE browser (all versions till IE 10). **[Issue](http://jsfiddle.net/DZAKg/)**

Text in input box is overlapping its background image. I cant put this image in parent div as its a dynamic input box and having lot of other functionality. and i cant increase the width of textbox than 100px and value is about 50 characters.

pls help.

**CSS**

```
.some {
background:url(http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/windowsphone/en-us/How-to/wp8/inline/hardware-icon-search-button.png) no-repeat right center;
padding:1px 15px 1px 1px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
width:100px;
color:red;
overflow:hidden;}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="some" value="I am a messy input box" />
```

Comment: What if you increase the padding to 30 .. `padding:1px 30px 1px 1px;
` .. does that move your image?

Comment: @PellePanna: No, its just increase the width of input box and text overlap the image. Actually i cant increase the width of textbox than 100px and value is about 50 characters. thx

Comment: As per sanjeev answer, increase right padding. It will works cool.

Comment: Which versions of IE you need to support?  .. 8 or 9, or both..

Comment: @PellPenna: from ie8 to ie 10 at least

Comment: Last question: what doctype does your webpage have?

Comment: Ok .. I found another issue with quirks mode when doctype is not set and wanted to make sure you had set yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this demo with IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/74u4w/2/

If it works, just add the border to the image and you will have a fix

```
.some {
    background-image: url(http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/windowsphone/en-us/How-to/wp8/inline/hardware-icon-search-button.png);
    background-position: 105px -6px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    width: 100px;
    color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If not, then the last resort is a small javascript that appends an img/div after your input. (which can be done dynamically)

With an absolute position set, it will not affect the flow. This css sample shows how it could look:

```
.some {
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 80px;                   /* narrowed to fit img */
    color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.someimg {
    background-image: url(http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/windowsphone/en-us/How-to/wp8/inline/hardware-icon-search-button.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: ?px;            /* needs to be calculated based on each input */
    top: ?px;             /* needs to be calculated based on each input */
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: As perfect as it can be, as there are no other ways to fix it in IE .. and good that it works out for you

Comment: Actually, perfect with the existing layout. thnks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease `input` field `width` and add `padding` from right

DEMO [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DZAKg/1/)

Comment: check in IE @Girish, its still overlapping the image.

Comment: @Era it wont work in IE browser, you can add `span` or other element for search icon...

Comment: @Era, why you want to do it?, if you will have get done then also you can't attach any event on `search icon`..